# Drag and select the object in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs, drag

I need to drag and select the object in fabric.js just by dragging and selecting a small portion of it. Setting 'selectionFullyContained: false' helps us to select it. But if we drag anywhere within the borders select the object.It is the default behaviour of fabric.js.

I need to select the object only when the drag and selection is made exactly on the object.

[Dragging the mouse anywhere within the borders select the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEfUf.png)
I need to select the object only when the drag and selection is made exactly on the object(that is the black lined borders)

Please note that we can select and drag exactly the object by setting perPixelFindTarget to true.But I need to select the object using mousedrag

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.